# Element has no attached source code Java.Lang

Tags: java, javadoc

Hello I am trying to use the Double Object, rather then the type in order to synchronize threads. This is a homework assignment.

Overview: This application is a trivial example of a banking system, it has thread that run as the depositors and threads that run as the withdrawers. depositors add 10$ and withdrawers remove 10$ so the end of the application should have 10 bank accounts that are unchanged.

In each class (depositors and withdrawers) i was able to use block synchronization on the account object to accomplish the goal. So the homework part of my assignment is finished, and i don't need help with that.

I got to thinking, and i feel like locking the entire Account object is overkill. Since the only real part of the transaction that is critical is changing the variable

```
 balance
```

originally the variable balance was a double. My goal, was to change the variable to the Double object, and then move the synchronization block to the inside the account object and only around the parts of the code that modify the balance variable.

When i changed the code to Double, there is no error but i get a note:

```
This element has no attached source and the Javadoc could not be found in the attached Javadoc
```

Also, the code does not work as my values come out all wrong at the end.

Questions:

1. Is my theory correct, that i should be able to lock only the Balance variable?
2. How can i get my code to recognize the Java.lang code for Double?

Thanks

Here is some code...

Declaration:

```
private Double balance;
```

Constructor:

```
this.balance = new Double(balance);
```

Locking:

```
synchronized(balance){

balance = balance + amount;

}
```

Comment: In your second question there should be "java.lang" not "Java.lang" (in package names we use only lower case letters).

Comment: It's true that sometimes, locking an entire object is overkill and bad for performance. But on the other hand it is sometimes not enough to lock the calls on the critical resource. Some actions have to be done "atomically" and thus have to be locked as a block. Often "read-change-write"-blocks are candidates for this. You won't want another thread change the resource after you've been changing it and have not written it back yet.

Comment: @JB what code do you want to see? this is a very trivial example. and more a question about the theory. I don't think posting 2 lines of code is going to help anything.

Comment: I think JB Nizet wanted to see code that reproduce your problem. If it is possible then post some [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) or you probably wont see correct answers.

Comment: P.S i do not appreciate the the -1 vote, from someone the doesn't understand the question. There is clearly effort put into the problem.

Comment: @Special--k - votes are not for effort.  They are for the quality of the Question.  The fact that people do not understand the question is partly a reflection on the way that the question is written.

Comment: i cant see how to make the question an more clear. This is a threading example, so i also cannot see how to make a SSCCE that could simulate the issue as it requires atleast 4 classes. Perhaphs a comment asking specific question would be better then just voting down? I have no problem trying to help explain the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is my theory correct, that i should be able to lock only the Balance variable?

No.

```
synchronized(balance) {
    balance = balance + amount;
}
```

When you lock on `balance`, you are really locking the `Double` instance that is the *value of* `balance`, and not on the `balance` variable.  But then you *replace* the value in `balance` with a different `Double` instance.  If some other thread comes along, it may see the new `Double` and acquire the lock on it before the current thread has released the lock that it (still) holds on the old `Double`.  In other words, you don't get proper mutual exclusion.  Furthermore, the preconditions for a "happens-before" relationship are not met, and the threads may therefore see inconsistent versions of the shared variable and objects.

If you want to lock an instance variable, you need to lock the object that it is an instance of.

---

> How can i get my code to recognize the Java.lang code for Double?

This is an IDE issue.  The IDE cannot find the source JAR file that corresponds to the "rt.jar" file the IDE has been configured to use.  This is most likely because you've to the IDE to use the "rt.jar" file in a JRE.  The solution is to reconfigure your IDE to use the JDK that corresponds to the JRE.

Note that this doesn't alter the way that your program works.  It only affects the IDE's ability to show you source code when (for example) you single step into a core class.